# How do you select an <li> that has no content?

Tags: jquery

So the `li`'s in reference do not contain anything, but they do have a `val == ""` which means that the selector :

```
$("li:empty")
```

.. will not work.

How can I simply select all the `li`'s that do not have anything in them?

Comment: Does the li's have some css class or id in it?

Comment: What do you mean they have `val == ""`, and why won't `:empty` work?

Comment: Can you post some of your HTML or make a Fiddle on jsfiddle.net ? I've just tested putting an empty LI in a page and $("li:empty") selected it.

Comment: @patrick dw, because a value of "" is techinically not `empty`

Comment: Are you talking about a `value` attribute? What would that have to do with `:empty`?

Comment: @patrick: because attributes are also considered nodes.

Comment: @Braveyard: An attribute on an element would *not* have any effect on `:empty`, which looks at content.

Comment: @patrick: Would you like to try in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @patrick: Please check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/cDUES/

Comment: @Braveyard: Yes, there are 2 empty `<p>` elements, and the result shows `2`. I'm not sure what your point is. Are you getting a different result in a different browser? I tested in Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

Comment: @Patrick: My point is OP only wants `<p></p>` and that's why he cannot use `:empty` selector.

Comment: @Braveyard: No, that's not what he wanted. He said `val == ""` would *break* the `:empty` selector, which it doesn't, as your demonstration shows. Turns out that `val == ""` was his way of referring to a child `<a>` element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$("li").filter(function(){ return $(this).html() == ''; });
```

Comment: This isn't any different from doing `:empty`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm doing that works. Is there anything better?

```
$('li:not(:has(>a))')
```

Comment: I thought you said the `li`s do not contain anything.

Comment: You mean you want to find `li`'s which do not have `a` as a child?

Comment: ideally, i'd like to just target empty li's but this also gets the job done.

Comment: Now I really can't tell what you're asking. If you only want empty ones, use `:empty`. If they contain a text node, even an one with only whitespace, then it isn't empty.

Comment: Yah i'm not sure what to say, but ":empty" didn't work. Evidently having a whitespace in a value was not considered `empty` by jQuery's standards.

Comment: @Trip: That's correct. Would you like a solution that ignores white space?

Comment: Patrick DW: Surely! I'd very much like to hear your idea as I'm a big fan of your answers.